# File won't compile, what to change?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, types

My program won't compile and I don't completely understand why. If you could tell me what I need to add or change that would be great! This code is meant to take a list of data from file "Names.txt" and and analyze it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String selection, nameIn, nameIn2;
        Name name, name2;
        int decade;
        String first = "1", second = "2", third = "3", fourth = "4", fifth = "5", sixth = "6", seventh = "7", eighth = "8", ninth = "9", tenth = "10";
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the character corresponding to your selection:");
            System.out.println("a - Print histogram for a name");
            System.out.println("b - Compare two names in a decade");
            System.out.println("c - Print top ten names for a decade");
            System.out.println("d - Quit (display file anomalies)");
            selection = stdin.next();
            System.out.println("your selection: " + selection);
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                nameIn = stdin.next();
                name = nameIn.findName();
                System.out.println("Histogram for name, " + name.getName());
            }
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                nameIn = stdin.next();
                name = nameIn.findName();
                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                nameIn2 = stdin.next();
                name2 = nameIn.findName();
                System.out.println("Enter number corresponding to your decade:");
                System.out.println("1 - 1900-1909");
                System.out.println("2 - 1910-1919");
                System.out.println("1 - 1920-1929");
                System.out.println("1 - 1930-1939");
                System.out.println("1 - 1940-1949");
                System.out.println("1 - 1950-1959");
                System.out.println("1 - 1960-1969");
                System.out.println("1 - 1970-1979");
                System.out.println("1 - 1980-1989");
                System.out.println("1 - 1990-1999");
                System.out.println("1 - 2000-2005");
                System.out.println("Enter a decade: ");
                decade = stdin.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Data for " + name.getName());
                System.out.println(name.getHistoLine(decade));
                System.out.println("Date for " + name2.getName());
                System.out.println(name2.getHistoLine(decade));
            }
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                System.out.println("Enter number corresponding to your decade:");
                System.out.println("1 - 1900-1909");
                System.out.println("2 - 1910-1919");
                System.out.println("1 - 1920-1929");
                System.out.println("1 - 1930-1939");
                System.out.println("1 - 1940-1949");
                System.out.println("1 - 1950-1959");
                System.out.println("1 - 1960-1969");
                System.out.println("1 - 1970-1979");
                System.out.println("1 - 1980-1989");
                System.out.println("1 - 1990-1999");
                System.out.println("1 - 2000-2005");
                System.out.println("Enter a decade: ");
                decade = stdin.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ten most popular names (male and female) during the decade 1990-1999 were: ");
                System.out.println(first.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(second.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(third.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(fourth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(fifth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(sixth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(seventh.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(eighth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(ninth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(tenth.findRank(decade));
            }
            if (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("b") || !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("C") || !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
                ;
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
            }
        }
        while (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d"));
        if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        }
    }

    public Static Name findName() {
        String fileName = "Names.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file" + inputStream);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String line;
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] nameLine = line.split(" ");
            String babyName = nameLine[0];
            int[] popularity;
            for (int k = 0; k < nameLine.length; k++) {
                popularity[k] = Integer.parseInt(nameLine[k + 1]);
            }
            if (this.equalsIgnoreCase(babyName)) {
                Name name = new Name(babyName, popularity);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Sorry that name was not found");
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    public Static String findRank(int decade) {
        String fileName = "Names.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file" + inputStream);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String top = "";
        String line;
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] nameLine = line.split(" ");
            String babyName = nameLine[0];
            int[] popularity;
            for (int k = 0; k < nameLine.length; k++) {
                popularity[k] = Integer.parseInt(nameLine[k + 1]);
            }
            if (popularity[decade - 1] == Integer.parseInt(this)) {
                top = top + babyName + "(" + this + ")" + "        ";
            }
            return top;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the compilation errors:

```
NameApp.java:126: ';' expected
    public Static Name findName()
                      ^
NameApp.java:126: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public Static Name findName()
                       ^
NameApp.java:161: ';' expected
    public Static String findRank(int decade)
                        ^
NameApp.java:161: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public Static String findRank(int decade)
                         ^
4 errors
```

Comment: You just asked this an hour ago. You really should just read a tutorial.

Comment: I think I'll answer this on your duplicate post.  There's a lot more to it than just capitalization of a keyword or two.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case-sensitive. The `static` keyword must be lowercase. Your code does not have `static` in all-lowercase; therefore, the compiler interprets `Static` as a return type, interprets the actual return type as the name, and then chokes on the actual name.

To fix this, simply change `Static` to `static` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the function declaration, use 'static' instead of 'Static'

Comment: should i be using static at all?

Comment: you should use static keyword in function that you believe not belong to any instantiated object, ie. a function for the class.